# ASP display day of week

Tags: asp-classic

how to  display day of week with VB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MsgBox WeekdayName(Weekday(Now))

Comment: I didn't think that function was available in vbscript.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Is available from Microsoft Visual Basic Scripting Edition version 2.0 onwards.